# JSP string with "enter" causing problems

Tags: java, javascript, string, google-app-engine, jsp

I have app engine app that uses a java servlet to save a message to the datastore that is posted by a user (using a form).

```
String content = req.getParameter("message");
message.setProperty("content", content);
```

When later processing the message in JSP I get a run-time error if the user has hit "enter" when typing the message.

```
messageArray[<%=i%>]= {
                    content:  "<%=message.getProperty("content")%>",
```

How do I solve this?  I would like to save the "enter" to display the message properly.

Thanks!

Comment: show us that run-time error .. but first try _"<%=message.getProperty("content").replace("/n","")%>"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use something like JSON encoding to make the string safe for inclusion into JavaScript source. You should do that anyway to prevent an obvious XSS attack.

JavaScript doesn't allow raw newlines in string constants.  If you wanted to you could create your own EL function to sanitize the string, converting non-printable characters to `\uXXXX` escapes, and making sure that embedded quotes are preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Could you share a few details on the JSON encoding? Is this something I should do server side or through javascript?

Comment: It has to be done server-side. There's a [Google toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) that you could use, either directly or wrapped up in your own EL function.

Comment: Will just encoding the string as an JSON object and then extracting it with .String() be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I think so - I've never used the Google tools but I *think* that's how they work.  It should be pretty easy to set up a test case.

Comment: So I set it up and tested it but it didn't work.  I end up doing what Catalin suggested above.  I would though like to protect it against attacks